# Changing a Variable in Another File from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, appdelegate

### Background

I am trying to access the variable `managedObjectContext` that is in `ProjectsController.swift` from `AppDelegate.swift`.

### Code

In `ProjectsController.swift`:

```
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil

var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Project> {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Project> = Project.fetchRequest()

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: false)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]




    //The output is "nil"
    print(self.managedObjectContext as Any)

    //Couldn't unwrap optional value (self.managedContext!)
    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Master")





    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

    do {
        try _fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
    } catch {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        let nserror = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController!
}
```

In `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
let projectsViewController = ProjectsViewController()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    //The output prints both of the print statements, so it has executed the change in variable.  The viewContext also outputs as it is supposed to.
    print(self.persistentContainer.viewContext)
    //Here is where the variable changes
    projectsViewController.managedObjectContext = self.persistentContainer.viewContext
    print(true)
    return true
}
```

### Question

I'm just wondering why, even when I have updated the variable from `AppDelegate.swift`, `ProjectsController.swift` can't unwrap the value because it is still `nil`.  Is there something wrong with the connections, or maybe is there a better way to access a variable in a different file from `AppDelegate.swift`.

### Extra info:

- `ProjectsController` is inside a Navigation View Controller
- I am using Swift 3

### Closing

I can't think of any other information to give, I am a beginner with Swift, so please let me know if you need extra information to solve this problem, or if it can't be solved.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: projectsViewController where declared and initilised ?

Comment: you cant do this because you cant not get reference of navigation controller in appdelegate .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will happen if you use the fetchedResultsController before its managedObjectContext is set. e.g. if the view controller tries to fetch data as soon as it is loaded, and before you get a chance to run the code in your app delegate that sets the managedObjectContext.

Suggest that you try to keep the creation of the ProjectsViewController together with its dependencies, this way it is never in an unusable state. For example, in your app delegate:

```
let projectsViewController: ProjectsViewController = {
    let vc = ProjectsViewController()
    vc.managedObjectContext = self.persistentContainer.viewContext
    return vc
}()
```

This code declares the projectsViewController to be the value of a closure (effectively a function) that is executed immediately .